# How to remove Dropped map marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, google-maps-markers

I wan to make android back button get one step to back and remove the dropped marker in is there any possible way to  do that?

```
public AddMarker(){
    let image = '/assets/img/rsz_marker.png';   
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter()
    , icon: image
  }); 
  }
    platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      if (this.nav.canGoBack()) {
        this.nav.pop();
      } else {
         //*remove marker?
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a marker from your map, you can use the api call `setMap()`

```
marker.setMap(null)
```

Pass in `null` to set the marker to `null`

For more information, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove